# Is there a verb to convey the meaning of memorizing too much?

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb to use for expressing memorizing something too much to the extent that the speaker wouldn't be concentrating on what s/he is **actually** saying, so the words would come out as meaningless to him/her.

It may appear as a positive or negative thing depending on the situation.

We have it in Arabic "بَصَمَ" (pronounced as Basama), it is in its past simple form.

Example:

> He _______ (memorized) his section after getting rebuked by his teacher.

The word would fill the blank instead of "memorized".

Comment: I can't think of such a verb, but the phrase [learn by rote](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/learn+by+rote) might come close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you mean things like as schoolchild learning to recite a poem by heart, without having the slightest idea what it ***means**?* That's sometimes called [rote learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rote_learning) - but it's based on the idea of ***repetition*** as an aid to memorization, which doesn't seem central to your context.

Comment: I've used "scripted" before in the context you're describing (e.g, I memorized/scripted a response to a question while not knowing what the answer really means), but not sure if that is exactly what you're looking for

Comment: @FumbleFingers _ Thank you so much! I believe you are right that it won't be a very good fit to what I've described as it is _also_ more of a technique. About the first question, no, it is not related to any specific age group.

Comment: @Wondercricket _ "Scripted" seems to make a great suggestion. Thank you so much! But could you please clarify it more? I find it the nearest, if not exactly, what I'm looking for.

Comment: @CanadianYankee _ Thank you so much! "Learn by rote" makes indeed a very suitable phrase. But its compound noun (rote learning), which FumbleFingers has proposed, clarifies it a bit differently.

Comment: I was actually just about to add *by rote* as an answer, but then read these comments. Note that in *rote learning*, *rote* is a noun, but in [*memorized by rote*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rote), *rote* is an adjective. If this is not an acceptable answer, I don't think you're going to find one.

Comment: @JasonBassford _ It is an acceptable answer indeed. If you read the comments, then you surely noticed that although I mentioned the difference issue, I didn't reject the suggestion. If the user wasn't willing to return to clarify and/or solve the dilemma, then what else is there to say.

Comment: You might find "over-rehearsed" is close: it doesn't mean the speaker doesn't understand the words, only that they are spoken in such a dull way it seems insincere.  The effect of seeing or saying a word until it's meaningless is called "semantic satiation", but that would only ever be used in an academic context

Comment: @jonathanjo _ **Over-rehearsed** seems to fit exactly what I want to express. In fact, I didn't mean _not understanding the words_ literally. But like your description of the situation, which is to say the script in a dull way without feeling the words and its meanings. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find "**over-rehearsed**" is close, but it's only negative: it doesn't mean the speaker doesn't understand the words, only that they are spoken in such a dull way it seems insincere.

You can use it like this:

- **He over-rehearsed his answer and didn't sound convincing at all.**
- **He had over-rehearsed his speech and there was no passion in his voice.**

This also applies literally to musicians or actors.

The effect of seeing or saying a word until it's meaningless is called "**semantic satiation**", but that would only ever be used in an academic context.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_satiation)

For a positive description:

- **He worked so hard he knew it by heart**
- **He worked so hard he knew it backwards**

Comment: It is a good step that you've attached the Wikipedia link page as I haven't searched that term but only the first one when you have inserted the comment. It makes a great fit too. Thanks again!